# spark UDF pattern matching for multiple columns and collection elements

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

Given `df` as below:

[image]

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
(1, 2, 3),
(3, 2, 1)
)).toDF("One", "Two", "Three")
```

with schema:
[image]

I would like to write a `udf` that takes `Three columns` as inout; and returns new column based on highest input value similar as below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf


def udfScoreToCategory=udf((One: Int, Two: Int, Three: Int): Int => {
    cols match {
    case cols if One > Two && One > Three => 1
    case cols if Two > One && Two > Three => 2
    case _ => 0
}}
```

It will be interesting to see how to do similar with `vector type` as input:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector

def udfVectorToCategory=udf((cols:org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector): Int => {
    cols match {
    case cols if cols(0) > cols(1) && cols(0) > cols(2) => 1,
    case cols if cols(1) > cols(0) && cols(1) > cols(2) => 2
    case _ => 0
}})
```

Comment: Question is how to pass multiple columns to `udf` and perform pattern matching as per ` invalid syntax` examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems:

- `cols` in the first example are not in the scope.
- `(...): T => ...`  is not valid syntax for anonymous function.
- It is better to use `val` over `def` here.

One way to define this:

```
val udfScoreToCategory = udf[Int, (Int, Int, Int)]{
  case (one, two, three) if one > two && one > three => 1
  case (one, two, three) if two > one && two > three => 2
  case _ => 0
}
```

and

```
val udfVectorToCategory = udf[Int, org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector]{
  _.toArray match {
    case Array(one, two, three) if one > two && one > three => 1
    case Array(one, two, three) if two > one && two > three => 2
    case _ => 0
}}
```

In general, for the first case you should use ``when`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when

when ($"one" > $"two" && $"one" > $"three", 1)
  .when ($"two" > $"one" && $"two" > $"three", 2)
  .otherwise(0)
```

where `one`, `two`, `three` are column names.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the biggest element of the vector by:

```
  val vectorToCluster = udf{ (x: Vector) => x.argmax }
```

However, I am still puzzled how to do pattern matching on multiple columns values.